# NSLayoutConstraint providing width but not height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I create a custom UIView:

[image]

I am using NSLayoutConstraints to create the layout and size. Since `UIView` does not have an 'intrinsic size' like `UILabel` or `UITextField` have, I set the view's `NSLayoutAttributeBottom` equal plus 20 to the lowest subview. This forces the view to stretch down and to the right, giving it size depending on the the location of its subviews.

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topBarView]-[nameLabel]"
                      options:0
                      metrics:nil
                      views:views]];
NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewBottomConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:imageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1 constant:20];
imageViewBottomConstraint.priority = 400;
[self addConstraint:imageViewBottomConstraint];
```

I set the bottom attribute to the imageView (blue box with gear image) and set the priority.

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nameLabel][nameTextField]-(8@600)-[commentsLabel]-(0@600)-[commentsTextView]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                      metrics:nil
                      views:views]];
NSLayoutConstraint *commentsTextViewBottomConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:commentsTextView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                            multiplier:1 constant:20];
commentsTextViewBottomConstraint.priority = 300;
[self addConstraint:commentsTextViewBottomConstraint];
```

I also set the bottom attribute to the comments text view with a lower priority so it will break easily.

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[imageView]-(50)-[nameTextField]"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                      metrics:nil
                      views:views]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                     constraintWithItem:commentsTextView
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                     toItem:nameTextField
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                     multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nameTextField
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                multiplier:1 constant:20]];
```

And then I set the right attribute to give it width.

I'm running into an issue where the height is 0 until I add it to a subview:

```
PhotoDisplayPanel *photoPanel = [[PhotoDisplayPanel alloc] initWithPhotoData:nil];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

DLog(@"BEFORE | photoPanel.frame.size: (%f, %f)", photoPanel.frame.size.width, photoPanel.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:photoPanel];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

DLog(@"AFTER | photoPanel.frame.size: (%f, %f)", photoPanel.frame.size.width, photoPanel.frame.size.height);
```

result:

```
DEBUG | -[PhotoDisplayPanel initWithPhotoData:] | self.frame.size: (790.000000, 0.000000)
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | BEFORE | photoPanel.frame.size: (790.000000, 0.000000)
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | AFTER | photoPanel.frame.size: (790.000000, 389.000000)
```

I'm confused why the view has a width but not a height before adding it to the view. This is an issue I'm running into when trying to set the view into a `UIPopoverController`.

EDIT:

After playing around with it, the cause is the priority's I add to the 2 bottom attribute constraints. I removed the 'commentsTextViewbottomConstraint' constraint and removed the priority on the `imageViewBottomConstraint', and it almost works:

```
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topBarView]-[nameLabel]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:20];
//    imageViewBottomConstraint.priority = 400;
    [self addConstraint:imageViewBottomConstraint];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[nameLabel][nameTextField]-(8@600)-[commentsLabel]-(0@600)-[commentsTextView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading metrics:nil views:views]];
//    NSLayoutConstraint *commentsTextViewBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:commentsTextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:20];
//    commentsTextViewBottomConstraint.priority = 300;
//    [self addConstraint:commentsTextViewBottomConstraint];
```

The new result:

```
DEBUG | -[PhotoDisplayPanel initWithPhotoData:] | self.frame.size: (590.000000, 572.000000)
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | BEFORE | photoPanel.frame.size: (590.000000, 572.000000)
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | AFTER | photoPanel.frame.size: (590.000000, 589.000000)
```

I developed the code this way so if the image view was larger then where the bottom attribure of the text view was, it would stretch to show the full image. Or, if the image was smaller then the text view's bottom attribute, it would maintain a minimum height to show the text view, such as:

[image]

Any idea how I can maintain this feature?

Comment: No layout is performed until the view is in the interface. So there is no such thing as size "before adding it to the view".

Comment: This is true unless you set the view's height. You can create a view and set the width/height constraints. Since the width/height is set, it does not need to generate width/height and will show before adding to the subview. If the width/height is not set, then the layout does need to be generated before you can see its width/height (or you can use `[UIView layoutIfNeeded]` to do the same as adding it to a view.